# Bootstrap Arrow , hamburger menu is ok in offline mode but not getting displayed online

Tags: bootstrap-4

In my website I am using bootstrap libraries offline after downloading them like following

```css
 <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="assets/vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/icofont/icofont.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/remixicon/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
  <link href="assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

it is working fine in offlie mode but when I am going live the navigation icon , hamburger icon and corousel icon are not getting displayed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8CAO.png)

Comment: Can you share the example instead of the image? Do you use any scripts?

Comment: it seems like you're missing the font(awesome). Make sure the font gets loaded and is available. please include the code where you include this.